# Does accept function return error(-1) if TCP server goes out of network

Tags: linux, sockets, tcp

Does the accept function returns error(-1) if the Ethernet interface it is attached goes out of network?if not how does the application(TCP server) will know that its interface is not active any more ??

I am using one thread for accepting the connection and not using any "select" statement for doing so.Directly calling accept() function but somehow it is not retuning error if I remove the IP address from Ethernet interface.

using C and working environment is linux.

Comment: Pick a language ... any language ...

Comment: I am not sure it does quickly, because TCP has some timeouts which are bigger than a minute. Still, using `select` or `poll` is always sensible...

Comment: @Basile Starynkevitch These timer helps once we close the socket connection.I am just trying to find out how an application server will know that interface is no more active

Comment: @Brian Roach Just edited my post.Can you please comment it now.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you don't bind your server socket to a specific IP address (you use INADDR_ANY). So even if you remove your ethernet IP address, you could still contact your server using the loopback interface. Or some other interface with an IP address.

If you want to make sure that your server is reachable from the net, checking the interface status does not get you much. It's just a single hop on a long path through the network. You'd need a testing client somewhere else to check the reachability of your server.